# Composite Strategy pattern - java - How bad is this code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop, rules, strategy-pattern

This question is kind of continuation to my earlier post: [Visitor pattern implementation in java- How does this look?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944824/visitor-pattern-implementation-in-java-how-does-this-look)

I got a bit confused while refactoring my code. I am trying to convert my visitor pattern (explained in the prior post) into a composite strategy pattern. I am trying to do something like this:

```
public interface Rule {
  public List<ValidatonError> check(Validatable validatable);
}
```

Now, I would define a Rule like this:

```
public class ValidCountryRule  {
  public List<ValidationError> check(Validatable validatable) {
    // invokeDAO and do something, if violation met
    // add to a list of ValidationErrors.
    // return the list.
  }
}
```

Now, I could have two different types objects to be validated. These two could be completely different: Say I have a Store that is `Validatable`, and then a `Schedule` which is `Validatable`. Now, if I would write a composite that would look like this:

```
class Validator implements Rule {
  private List<Rule> tests = new ArrayList<Rule>();

  public void addRule(Rule rule) {
    tests.add(rule);
  }

  public List<ValidationError> check(Visitable visitable) {
    List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
    for(Rule rule : tests) {
      list.addAll(rule.check(visitable);
    }
  }

  public Validator(ValidatorType type) {
    this.tests = type.getRules();
  }
}
```

I would define an `enum` that defines what set of checks go where...

```
public Enum ValidatorType {
  public abstract List<Rule> getRules();
  STORE_VALIDATOR {
    public List<Rule> getRules() {
      List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();
      rules.add(new ValidCountryRule());
      rules.add(new ValidXYZRule());
    }

  // more validators
}
```

and finally, I would use it like this:

```
Validator validator = new Validator(ValidatorType.STORE_VALIDATOR);
for (Store store : stores) {
  validator.check(store);
}
```

I have a strange feeling that my design is flawed. I am not liking the idea that my Rule interface expects a `Validatable`. Could you please suggest how I would improve this?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace Validatable by a generic type parameter T to make the validation framework type safe.

```
public interface Rule<T> {
    public List<ValidationError> check(T value);
}
```

Let's extend our framework with an interface ValidationStrategy:

```
public interface ValidationStrategy<T> {
    public List<Rule<? super T>> getRules();
}
```

We are dealing with rules bounded by "? super T" so we can add a rule for Animal to a Dog Validator (assuming Dog extends Animal). The Validator now looks like this:

```
public class Validator<T> implements Rule<T> {
    private List<Rule<? super T>> tests = new ArrayList<Rule<? super T>>();

    public Validator(ValidationStrategy<T> type) {
        this.tests = type.getRules();
    }

    public void addRule(Rule<? super T> rule) {
        tests.add(rule);
    }

    public List<ValidationError> check(T value) {
        List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        for (Rule<? super T> rule : tests) {
            list.addAll(rule.check(value));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now we can implement a sample DogValidationStrategy like this:

```
public class DogValidationStrategy implements ValidationStrategy<Dog> {
    public List<Rule<? super Dog>> getRules() {
        List<Rule<? super Dog>> rules = new ArrayList<Rule<? super Dog>>();
        rules.add(new Rule<Dog>() {
            public List<ValidationError> check(Dog dog) {
                // dog check...
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
        });
        rules.add(new Rule<Animal>() {
            public List<ValidationError> check(Animal animal) {
                // animal check...
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
        });
        return rules;
    }
}
```

Or, like in your sample, we may have an Enum providing several dog validation strategies:

```
public enum DogValidationType implements ValidationStrategy<Dog> {
    STRATEGY_1 {
        public List<Rule<? super Dog>> getRules() {
            // answer rules...
        }
    },
    // more dog validation strategies
}
```

Comment: @chris Thank you, your answer helps. I have one question. In Dog ValidationStrategy, I would like ? extends Animal not ? super Dog. This would ensure that a single rule can be applied to Dog and Cat. Now, when I try declaring everything as T extends Animal, compiler complains about the for loop in Validator class. I get this error message: The method check(capture-of ? extends Animal) in the type Rule<capture-of ? extends Animal> is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Comment: @chris your answer is the closest to what I want, if you can answer my comment, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Jay, if a rule is meant to be applied to dogs *and* cats, shouldn't that be an animal rule? If you could do what you described, a cat rule may be passed in a dog in check(animal).

Answer (score 9):

When I first learned about design patterns, I kept trying to find places to use them.  I've since learned that premature "patternization" is kind of like premature optimization.  First, try to do it in a straight-forward way, and then see what problems that gives you.

Try to design with minimal interfaces and subclassing.  Then apply whatever pattern may be appropriate for the obvious redundancies you find.  I get the impression from this and the previous post that you may be over-architecting your code.

Comment: @Jeremy what in particular is wrong with the code sample in the post above?

Comment: What if you just wrote:
for (Store store : stores) {
  validate_store(store);
}

At some point you're going to have to define which validation is performed on which types.  How is hard-coding it so much worse than adding all this complexity to your code and then externalizing it?

Before I nitpick on the code itself, I'm questioning the big picture.

Comment: @Jeremy: This sounds like doing the same work twice.
I recommend you to look at the TTP Toolkit at http://ttp.essex.ac.uk/
Also, whenever I see a pattern I use it. I use my past experience to solve problems. I also refer to the UML to see if I can refactor the design before I code.
This saves time, time is money.